# .Net Core 2.2 - Depois de publicar um WebApp, os links não estavam funcionando e o código HTML gerado era o mesmo que o Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Estou publicando um WebApp do Net Core (versão 2.2.108) no host SmaterAsp.net no modo "self-contained deployment".

Meu arquivo .CSPROJ se parece com isso:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <UserSecretsId>438bea06-a241-4638-a75d-2c9de371a6b3</UserSecretsId>
    <AssemblyName>ProjectName.UI.Web.Admin</AssemblyName>
    <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
    <MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Após publicar e executar o WebApp vi que os links não estavam funcionando e o código HTML gerado estava igual ao Razor, desse jeito:

```
<a asp-area="" asp-controller="Ticket" asp-action="Index">Tickets</a>
```

Mas o correto deveria ser:

```
<a href="/Ticket/Index">Tickets</a>
```

Se eu publicar sem os parâmetros abaixo:

```
<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>false</MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish>
```

Tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Error - The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=
```

Vocês sabem me dizer o que fiz de errado ou como ajustar isso?

Desde já, agradeço a sua atenção.

Comment: Não endenti... ele está retornando o cshtml como arquivo estático? você está acessando pela rota ou digitando o caminho do arquivo com a extensão?

Comment: Me desculpe Leandro, irei detalhar um pouco mais. Além do projeto WebApp, eu tenho outro projeto que é uma class library de ViewComponents idêntico a esse [projeto](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/07/2016-07-16-loading-view-components-from-a-class-library-in-asp-net-core/) que eu referencio no WebApp. Para aplicações .Net Core 2.2 funcionem no host, necessito publicar em modo self-contained deployment. Quando executo a aplicação no servidor alguns [links](https://imgur.com/fWVsj0u) (inspecionando o cod.) não são convertidos para HREF.

Comment: mas se você quer um link, o seu tag-helper está errado, não tem o `asp-area=""` seria só 
`<a asp-controller="Ticket"
   asp-action="Index">Tickets</a>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Dê uma olhada se está adequadamente importando a lib cm as tagHelpers. Dê uma olhada neste artigo: https://www.koskila.net/how-to-fix-microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-taghelpers-not-being-rendered/. Talvez possa ajudar a compreender o problema. Desconfiei de que talvez faltassem estes imports.

Veja se possui um arquivo _ViewImports.cshtml na pasta "Views" com o conteúdo:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Para ser mais específico e ajudar com erros comuns que possam ocorrer, segue o link da documentação relacionada, que trata do arquivo _ViewImports.cshtml. Ali ele explica exatamente como funciona, as diretivas para as quais ele dá suporte e também explica o seguinte:

> "O arquivo _ViewImports.cshtml para um aplicativo ASP.NET Core MVC
>   normalmente é colocado na pasta Pages (ou Views). Um arquivo
>   _ViewImports.cshtml pode ser colocado em qualquer pasta, caso em que só será aplicado a páginas ou exibições nessa pasta e em suas
>   subpastas. Arquivos _ViewImports são processados começando no nível
>   raiz e, em seguida, para cada pasta até o local da página ou da
>   exibição em si. As configurações _ViewImports especificadas no nível
>   raiz podem ser substituídas no nível da pasta."

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2#importing-shared-directives

E, como sugere o artigo, a falta deste arquivo leva ao erro informado na pergunta: As TagHelpers não são compiladas.

Agora sim, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Agora melhorou a resposta, mas seria interessante trazer o conteúdo do link externo para cá também, afinal a sua resposta vai ficar aqui, mas esse endereço pode ser desativado amanhã.

Comment: Oi Leandro, realmente não existe o arquivo _ViewImports.cshtml no projeto ViewComponentsLibrary. Irei ler o artigo que você informou, fazer os ajustes necessários e realizar o testes. O engraçado que executando localmente a situação não ocorre, ocorre só em ambiente de produção. Também irei ajustar a minha pergunta detalhando o que escrevi nos comentários, concordo com você. Obrigado pela atenção.